# Triggered send to single user via c# api does not send

Tags: marketing-cloud, api, c#

I have this code:

```
public void Send(string email)
        {
            CreateResult[] results;
            string requestId;
            string status;

            var t = new TriggeredSendDefinition { CustomerKey = "testthis" };
            t.RefreshContent = true;
            t.RefreshContentSpecified = true;
            var s = new TriggeredSend { TriggeredSendDefinition = t, Subscribers = new[] { new Subscriber{EmailAddress = email, SubscriberKey = email}  } };
            CreateResult[] r = Client.GetClient().Create(new CreateOptions(), new APIObject[] { s }, out requestId, out status);
            var r2 = (TriggeredSendCreateResult)r[0];
            //add your own try/catch, etc
        }
```

And the r2 variable returns a success result with the triggered send definition in the UI saying that 1 send is queued. But I never receive the email.

Can any one see what I'm doing wrong here?

Comment: You would be receiving error. Can you debug?

Comment: As I have stated, the r2 variable returns success - there is no error. StatusMessage: "Created TriggeredSend"